# How to create a where condition to an object inside an object in c# linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Let's say I have a class like:

```
public class TrainingPlan
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string TrainingPlanName { get; set; }
    public List<Training> TrainingList { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
  }
```

And a Training object inside it:

```
public class TrainingViewModel : AuditViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TrainingPlanId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ProjectViewModel ProjectObject { get; set; }
    public TrainingPlanViewModel TrainingPlanObject { get; set; }
}
```

I could write something like this in order to retrieve `TrainingPlans` where `IsDeleted = false` and also retrieve the `Training Objects` attached to it.

```
var result = _trainingPlanRepository.FindBy(t => t.ProjectId == projectId && t.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
```

But how do I set a condition for the Training objects where `IsDeleted = false` also?

Comment: Linq is a query and setting values requires a separate statement.So use : foreach(var r in result) { r.IsDeleted = true;}

Comment: @jdweng I don't think this is the question. OP wants to retrieve the items in the sublist where `!IsDeleted`

Comment: Instead of `TrainingViewModel ` add `Training` Model, to question

Comment: The OP said : But how do I set a condition for the Training objects where IsDeleted = false also?

Comment: yea the for loop solution is currently what Im using just so that I could finish the module but it would be nice if I didn't need a for loop for the query. I thought maybe there'd be a way to do it via linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var trainingPlans = _trainingPlanRepository
                    .Where(t => t.ProjectId == projectId && t.IsDeleted == false)
                    .ToList();
```

Now, In `trainingPlans` variable, All related `training` objects exist in it, so we want to filter it bases on `IsDelted` Property. so you can use below code:

```
foreach (var item in trainingPlans)
{
   item.trainingList = item.trainingList.Where(t => !t.IsDelete).ToList();
}
```

good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Any()` like below. **Assumption** Your `t` has a `List<Training>` which you want to query as well to get the non-deleted ones.

```
var result = _trainingPlanRepository.
             Where(t => t.ProjectId == projectId && !t.IsDeleted &&
             t.TrainingList.Any(x => !x.IsDeleted)).ToList();
```

Comment: `Any()` didn't filter data. It just determines whether a sequence contains an element or not. It means the result of your query (base on some condition) can return a `TrainingObject` which has `IsDelted = false`. so your query isn't an answer to this question

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi Why don't you try it once and see whether it works

Comment: I know It works, but it is obvious that it can contain wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a one-to-many relation (possibly many-to-many) between TrainingPlan and Training: every TrainingPlan has zero or more Tranings, and every Training belongs to exactly one TrainingPlan, namely the Training that the foreign key TrainingId (or something similar) refers to.

So somewhere deep inside your repository, you'll have two IQueryable sequences:

```
IQueryable<Training> trainings = ...
IQueryable<TrainingPlan> trainingPlans = ...
```

You want to query all trainingplans that are not deleted and that have a ProjectId equal to projectId, together with all its not deleted TrainingPlans.

Using method syntax this is fairly straightforward:

```
var result = trainingPlans

    // keep only the training plans you want to keep:
    .Where(trainingPlan => trainingPlan.ProjectId == projectId && !trainingPlan.IsDeleted)

    // GroupJoin each trainingPlan with its trainings:
    .GroupJoin(trainings,
    trainingPlan => trainingPlan.Id,           // from each training plan take the Id
    training => training.TrainingPlanId,       // from each training take the foreign key
    (trainingPlan, matchingTrainings) => new   // take the training plan with all its matching trainings
    {                                          // to make a new
         // Select the trainingplan properties you plan to use
         Id = trainingPlan.Id,
         Name = trainingPlan.Name,
         ...

         // Keep only the non-deleted trainings
         Trainings = matchingTrainings.Where(training => !training.IsDeleted)
             .Select(training => new
             {
                  // Select only the training properties that you plan to use:
                  Id = training.Id,
                  Date = training.Date,
                  ...

                  // not needed, you know the value:
                  // TrainingPlanId = training.TrainingPlanId,
             })
             .ToList(),
    });
```

Another method would be to remove the non-deleted trainings before the GroupJoin:

```
var validTrainingPlans = trainingPlans.Where(...);
var validTrainings = trainings.Where(training => !training.IsDeleted);
var result = validTrainingPlans.GroupJoin(validTrainings,
    ... etc
```